# Run Django function from Javascript command

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to have Django to run a function when I tell it based off a JavaScript button. How do I accomplish this? Where do I write the Django function?

#### JavaScript in main.html:

```
            function mainFunction(){
            alert("Beginning API Main Function");

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'livestream/postdata/',
                    success: function(){alert('DONE!');},
                    error:function(){alert('ERROR!');},
            });
            alert("ENDING API MAIN FUNCTION");
        }
```

#### Urls.py:

```
    url(r'^postdata$', 'livestream.views.postdata', name='postdata')
```

#### Views.py:

```
def postdata(request):

    r = ...api... (I know that the api works)
    print(r.text)
```

When I run the function 'mainFunction()' I get the two alerts and then another that says 'ERROR'. Why is this?

Comment: And this isn't cross site like in your other question?

Comment: ya, I'm going to take a different approach to the problem

Comment: I believe the url (in AJAX) should be: `url: '/livestream/postdata/',` (notice that first `/`?)

Comment: @HieuNguyen Thanks, but it didn't fix the issue of the error

Comment: Could you post your full view code then?

Comment: I can not for legal reasons. I know for a face that if the postdata function runs it will work. I have tested it in a python shell and it will return r.

Comment: Yeah it's working with shell doesn't mean it can work well with ajax, any line on the view can make the AJAX error. Typically it could be view throwing exception or doesn't render correctly.

Comment: Can I test it? I'm not even sure if the function is being called apron.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35038/discussion-between-hieu-nguyen-and-mhsmith21)

Answer (score 1):

Set up a route in your urls.py file

```
url(r'^action/$', 'yourproject.views.action', name='action')
```

In your views.py file, you would create that action.

```
def action(request):
  # do your magic!
```

Then, when someone interacts with that button, do an ajax call that hits the URL at /action.

Comment: I updated the question. I followed your code, but it doesn't seem to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

You add a listener to the button which makes an ajax call when fired. In your `view.py` you handle the response for that ajax call.

Comment: Can you explain how I do this? and where in the view.py I put the code? THanks

Answer (score 0):

@HieuNguyen

Thank You for answering my question. It was through chat, so I'll write down, what worked.

1. in ajax need a '/' before lifestream. /livestream/postdata/
2. url(r'^postdata/$', 'livestream.views.postdata', name='postdata')
3. in views.py

   before function I needed @csrf_exempt

   return HttpResponse(r)